# Re-rendering the page when an element in the 2D array changes in react native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, use-effect, use-state

I want to re-run the code below to reload the page whenever the value inside the invitation[1][1] changes, I update these array values using the AsyncStorage in another page, when I tried the following I got the error below.
Is there any other way to do so?

```
const [invitation, setInvitation] = React.useState(Array.from({length: 2},()=> Array.from({length: 2})));

  React.useEffect(()=>
  {
     getUserId();

  },invitation[1][1]);

    async function getUserId() {
      var keys = ["invitationFromURL","Alert"]
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys , (err, item) => 
        {
          setInvitation(item);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        // Error retrieving data
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    }  


  console.log(invitation);
  console.log(invitation[1][1]);
```

The error I get 
**Warning: %s received a final argument during this render, but not during the previous render. Even though the final argument is optional, its type cannot change between renders.%s, useEffect**

Comment: In case anyone comes here with the issue I had. I forgot to put the watched object in an array, and putting it in one removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have something like

```
const [invitation, setInvitation] = useState([[], []]);
```

up at the top of your component. That means on the first useEffect run `invitation[1][1]` will be null. On second run it will have a value. This is not kosher in React Native. When you call `useEffect` the final argument must have the same *type* every time the component renders.

Should be a simple fix -- instead of

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUserId();
  }, invitation[1][1]);
```

do

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUserId();
  }, invitation);
```

Comment: The solution you suggested results in an infinite loop.

Comment: Ah, in that case I don't think you actually want to be re-triggering useEffect every time `invitation` changes. Just remove the final argument from `useEffect` and see if that works. You get an infinite loop here because you are mutating `invitation` every time the component renders and the component renders every time `invitation` mutates.

Comment: If I removed it the page will never refresh, to make this more clear, I save a variable using AsyncStorage inside another page and then I navigate to this page but when I try to read and use the variable I get the previous saved value because the change is not reflected yet so I need to re-render the page to re-run the code so I can use the new saved value. 
I hope this is clear. Thank you.

Comment: The page can still refresh from reactive changes even without the last argument. The last argument will re-trigger specifically the useEffect, not the full re-render. Your use case sounds more like you want redux, apollo, or any other reactive cache. Another way to accomplish your task is to pass the variable in as props.